# Unable to Bind ID To Button with Table Generated Using SQLDataReader

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have been unable to figure this problem out. I used a `SqlDataReader` to generate data from my database into a grid view. I have been trying to generate buttons on each row, which I want to use to update the database.

I have been unable to get any values from the table to attach to the buttons. I am hoping to bind the ID but nothing I try works.

Here is my code for the original data binding query:

```
using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(constr))
{
    con.Open();

    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT ID, Width, Length, DockID from Slip where ID not in (select slipID from lease) and dockID = @dockId", con);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@dockId", dockId);

    SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
    gridView.DataSource = dr;
    gridView.DataBind();

    con.Close();
}
```

This is my attempt to generate buttons on each column, which work but I am unable to get any values from the table to bind to the buttons.

```
foreach (TableRow row in gvAvailableLeaseSlips.Rows)
{
    TableCell btnCell = new TableCell();
    Button btn = new Button();

    btn.Text = "Lease Slip";
    btn.CssClass = "btn";
    btn.Click += new EventHandler(BtnLease_Click);

    btnCell.Controls.Add(btn);

    row.Cells.Add(btnCell);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot bind a grid from a datareader like this. Change the code like

```
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        dt.Columns.Add("dockId");
        dt.Columns.Add("width");
        dt.Columns.Add("length");


        while (obj_Reader.Read())
        {
            DataRow row = dt.NewRow();
            row["dockId"] = obj_Reader["dockId"];
            row["width"] = obj_Reader["width"];
            row["lenght"] = obj_Reader["LName"];
            dt.Rows.Add(row);
        }
        gridView.DataSource = dt;
```

or you can use a dataset to fill the gridview

Also, in gridview, you can autogenerate edit button to update values
In gridview properties add AutoGnerateEditButton=true

Comment: This helped me a lot. Thank you for this.

Answer (score 0):

That's not how it is done. `GridView` has a DataKeys property which should be set to "ID" in your markup. Then in the click event handler for buttons, which seems to be present in each row according to your description, you should look for the corresponding `DataRow` and ask for its `DataKey` which will have your ID as an object.

Comment: P.S.: It has been many years since I have worked on ASP.NET, exact details may vary slightly but the process should be like what I wrote.

Answer (score 0):

after set Datakeys property for your GridView, It would be :

```
int rowIndex = gvAvailableLeaseSlips.RowIndex;
int ID = (int)gvAvailableLeaseSlips.DataKeys[rowIndex]["yourKey"];
```